# Adding elemets to set in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, set

In tests I need to create method which will return a set of elements. I have problems with adding elements to this set, constantly getting null pointer exception. I have created new set by cast

```
Set<T> newSet = (Set<T>) mock(Set.class);
```

but I have still problem adding any element to this set.

I do have method like this:

```
private Set<T> prepareData(){
T element1 = mock(T.class);
T element2 = mock(T.class);
when(element1.getText()).thenReturn('abc');
when(element1.getText()).thenReturn('def');

Set<T> set = new HashSet<>;
set.add(element1);
set.add(element2);

return set;
}
```

For list it all worked well, but I had to change it to set and have NPE in line adding element1 to set.

Comment: You have to tell mockito what to return when you call your set `when(newSet.get(eq(whateverIndexHere))).thenReturn(whatEverYourSetShouldReturnForThatIndex);`

Comment: What are you doing when you get the NPE? If you are adding things to the set and trying to get them back, it sounds like you didn't really want to mock the `Set` to start with.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a particular reason you want to mock the set instead of using an actual set?

Comment: Don't mock the set.  Use a real set, but possibly mock the elements inside it.

Comment: I do not have any particular reason to mock the set, I just want to add elements to set in order to prepare test data. How do I mock adding elements to created real set?